# C# HttpGet IHttpActionResult returns empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Hope everybody is having a good day.
I am using an API to read from a DB and then testing this API with Postman.

I have a c# class that looks like this:

```
{

    public class ResultValidSubscriptions
    {
        int ID;
        string Integration;
        string Domain;
        int Month;
        int Year;
        int UserCount;
        string AppVersion;
        bool IsCorrect;

        public ResultValidSubscriptions(int iD, string integration, string domain, int month, int year, int userCount, string appVersion, bool isCorrect)
        {
            ID = iD;
            Integration = integration;
            Domain = domain;
            Month = month;
            Year = year;
            UserCount = userCount;
            AppVersion = appVersion;
            IsCorrect = isCorrect;
        }
    }
}
```

So I retrieve a list of these objects  from the database and adding them to a list. I then use this method to return it to the caller(postman in this case).

```
  [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllValidSubscriptions(int TargetYear, int TargetMonth)
        {
            try
            {
                arrayListSubscriptions = service.getAllValidSubscriptions(TargetYear, TargetMonth);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayListSubscriptions);
                var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultValidSubscriptions>>(json);

                return Ok(deserialized);
            }
```

When I insert breakpoints I can see that arrayListSubscriptions contains the correct items. 5x ResultValidSubscriptions in this case. As you can see below the empty array also contains 5 items.

The problem is when I return either arrayListSubscriptions , Json, or deserialized all I get is an empty array.

[image]

When I change

```
return Ok(deserialized);
```

to

```
return Ok("hi");
```

It works fine and I see hi in postman. So my arraylist seems to be full, my method seems to be working. But somehow somewhere the array is getting cleared? I think the conversion to JSON is doing this, but I thought this would be solved by deserializing it with the class name.

Anybody that can help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: All your fields are private.

Comment: Already thought it had to be something stupid on my side. Thanks for the help! Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was the fields in my object class were private.

Changed to:

```
 public class ResultValidSubscriptions
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Integration;
        public string Domain;
        public int Month;
        public int Year;
        public int UserCount;
        public string AppVersion;
        public bool IsCorrect;

        public ResultValidSubscriptions(int iD, string integration, string domain, int month, int year, int userCount, string appVersion, bool isCorrect)
        {
            ID = iD;
            Integration = integration;
            Domain = domain;
            Month = month;
            Year = year;
            UserCount = userCount;
            AppVersion = appVersion;
            IsCorrect = isCorrect;
        }
    }
```

And it works! Sorry for the stupid oversight and thanks for the help!